# Compile & build qt4 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to compile and build Qt 4.8.3 from source. When I do ./configure, I get the following error message :

```
./configure: 183: ./configure: /^(QMAKE_CXX)=/ { print substr($0, index($0, "=") + 1) }: not found
ERROR: Cannot set the compiler for the configuration tests
```

Is this happening because I need to explicitly set the QMAKE_CXX variable? Thanks

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get build-dep qt` first

Comment: It looks like you don't have a C++ compiler installed. Try installing g++ first.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The problem seemed to be that I was using the source from the .zip file, instead of the source from the .tar.gz file. The difference is that the .zip is intended for windows, whereas the latter is intended for linux. I found the answer to this at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18899 where William mentions "It seems that you use the zip archive format which is for windows platform. Use the bz2 or gz format instead"

Comment: Note initally I was getting : 

"-bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

After fixing this in vi, I was then getting : 

"You don't seem to have 'make' or 'gmake' in your PATH.". It was only after fixing this that I was getting the error message above.

Comment: My adventures on building qt under ubuntu might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275551/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-multimedia-when-building-my-project-wi even if it is about both a different version of qt and ubuntu.