# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I am trying to compile [qGo](https://github.com/pzorin/qgo), after installing `qt5`

```
git clone https://github.com/pzorin/qgo.git
cd qgo
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

Right now the latest error is saying it can't find multimedia

```
# make
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/jdm/Downloads/qgo/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 3
```

I guessed the library `libqt5multimedia5` based on this question, but the computer it says its already there and the error persists.

```
libqt5multimedia5 is already the newest version.
```

---

There is another similar question but the user answered his own question.  I am not sure how it applies here:

- ["Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia" when building my project with fresh static Qt5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275551/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-multimedia-when-building-my-project-wi)

Comment: If you're using an existing Qt dev environment, be sure to check which version is defined in the Kits the project is using.

Answer (score 36):

I'm not able to post a comment, so I will write it as an answer. Your problem has been solved here:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/27608/unknown-module-multimedia/6

In order to handle the issue you should try installing packages that are absent:

```
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimedia5
```

and restart your Qt Creator after that.
Cheers.

**UPDATE.** If it will not work, try another solution:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep qtmultimedia5-dev
sudo apt-get source --compile qtmultimedia5-dev
```

**UPDATE 2** For me the solution was the following:

1. Download sources from http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0-rc/submodules/
2. Build them, add the library manually.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev` ought to do fine, as any sub-dependencies (`libqt5multimedia*`) would be satisfied consecutively by APT by itself.

Comment: Finally, this answer was useful for me to build BASIC256 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04:

`sudo apt-get install libpcre3=2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1`

`sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue on a Rocky 8 machine issue the following command:

`sudo yum install qt5-qtmultimedia-devel`

and install the requested package and its dependencies. The multimedia module should then be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I tried to build command line (i.e. qmake then make) I had a previous version (which qmake; qmake --version), and the Qt Creator has its own version installed when I installed Qt6.
When I used the Qt6 explicit qmake, the issue was resolved:

$ [basepath]/Qt/6.6.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake