# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts on Mac

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to deploy a local app, but the when I tried to do the qmake in terminal under the app folder directory, it has the error

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts

I have the qt chart installed in when I ran the QT installer, and I also have included

> QT       += charts

in the .pro file, I checked [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710908/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-charts) and [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948466/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-multimedia) but I don't know how to apply that in osx.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Qt do you have?, uninstall and reinstall Qt.

Comment: You have tried using Qt, maybe you have 2 Qt installed.

Comment: i uninstalled and reinstalled QT, same issue

Comment: i am thinking whether it is also due to i didn't uninstall QT correctly long time ago by just simply delete the QT folder

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200094/how-to-install-a-missing-qt-module) solved it for me. Basically, open MaintenanceTool.app in your Qt install folder, go to the version of Qt you have installed, expand it, and select charts (and anything else you want installed, but don't have installed).