# "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras" after installing from source

Tags: android, qt, cross-compiling

I have installed QT 5.7.1 from the qt-everywhere source tarball on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM. I configured QT with the following incantation:

```
./configure -nomake tests \
    -android-sdk /path/to/sdk \
    -android-ndk /path/to/sdk/ndk \
    -android-ndk-platform android-19 \
    -android-ndk-host linux-x86_64 \
    -android-arch armeabi-v7a
```

After that succeeded I did:

```
make
sudo make install
```

I have a project that has this specified:

```
QT += androidextras
```

When I build it (using `qmake && make`) I am getting the following error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras
```

I know that the qtandroidextras folder is inside of my QT source distribution, but it isn't being built and/or installed. I must be missing a step or configuration option somewhere, but I'm not familiar enough with QT or QT on Android development to spot it.

Comment: Struggled alot building all kinds of static versions of Qt and in the process I learned a few things. Most of them are summarized in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275551/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-multimedia-when-building-my-project-wi Maybe most relevant to you is where the log output from build is stored.

Comment: You haven't built the android module. Look at the configure or build output to see why it wasn't built.