# Qt Cross-Compile for Beaglebone Black

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to setting up Qt for Beaglebone Black by following this guide :

http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2013/07/building-qt-for-beaglebone/

My host machine is 64 bit ubuntu as virtual machine. I installed toolchain and qt. But when it comes to the configure qt with given parameters, i get this error :

Determining system architecture... (Linux:3.16.0-23-generic:x86_64)

64-bit AMD 80x86 (x86_64)

'arm' is supported

'x86_64' is supported

System architecture: 'arm'

Host architecture: 'x86_64'

ERROR: Cannot set the compiler for the configuration tests

I've been struggling with this for almost a week, and i've tried almost all parameters but got no luck.

Comment: Do you have the compiler under `/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin`?

Comment: @svlasov yeah. 

this is my  g++ --version output : g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1. And i can see arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ under the bin file.

Comment: You should be seeing `g++` symlink and not `arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++`. Although the compiler is specified in `QMAKE_CC`, try to set path to `/usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @svlasov I've tried this before, and just now, but still same error.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100276/compile-build-qt4-on-ubuntu-12-04